# Applying Bernoulli's Equation to siphon system giving negative value

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation

Consider the following situation when a tube is filled with water and inserted in a beaker where :
**h** = height of beaker
**y** = height at which opening of tube is
**$\rho$** = density of water

[image: Siphon system]

Now, I want to apply Bernoulli's equation to the surface of beaker and the exposed surface of tube.
I did the following :

\begin{align} P_1 + \frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2 + \rho g h_1 = P_2 + \frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2 + \rho g h_2\end{align}
Now, $ v_1 = 0$ and base of the container is the reference level for Potential energy where it is zero.
Let $P_0$ be the atmospheric pressure.
Putting the values :
\begin{align} P_0 + 0 + \rho g h = P_0 + \frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2 + \rho g y\end{align}
\begin{align} v_2^2 = 2 g (h - y) \end{align}
But the value of $v_2^2$ comes out be negative which is not possible.
What is the reason for it?

Comment: If $y>h$ the siphon won't work.

Comment: Then where will this water in the tube go since it is filled.